# PHP heredoc not retaining format

Tags: php, format, heredoc

Using the following code I expect to see 5 separate lines displayed. Instead it wraps everything together on one line... no tabs, no leading spaces, no blank line. Not what I was expecting.

After viewing other code, the programmer inserted a series of 's which I tried (using 
 instead) and got some of the results I was looking for. Am I expecting too much? I never could get leading spaces and tabs to work. Could this be a setup problem?

```
<?php
$author = "Alfred E Newman";

$out = <<<_END
       This is a Headline

   This is the first line.
   This is the second.
      - Written by $author.
_END;

print $out;
// echo $out; // ... didn't format as expected either
?>
```

Result: This is a Headline This is the first line. This is the second. - Written by Alfred E Newman.

Comment: Can't reproduce, the output looks good: http://codepad.org/7Oogl3hY ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you're outputting to HTML, try wrapping the `print` call in `<pre>` tags. A browser doesn't pay attention to OS newline characters when displaying HTML. **BUT**, if you view the page's source code you'll see the output formatted as expected there.

If you want new lines displayed in your HTML, you'll have to use `<br/>` or `<p>` or an appropriate CSS styling mechanism.

**UPDATE**

Oh and I forgot! As mentioned by the ever-vigilant @MarkBaker (thanks), PHP's [`nl2br`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function will handle such an operation for you by replacing newline characters with `<br/>` tags:

```
$output = nl2br($output);
print $output;
```

Comment: and don't forget the nl2br() function

Answer (score 4):

Just add a `header('Content-Type: text/plain;');` on top of your script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');
$author = "Alfred E Newman";
...
```

This tells your browser that it should display the output as plain text (not as HTML).